# Django - Access session in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to use a ListView to avoid creating a view for what should be quite a simple page.
Basically I want to list a set of objects related to the current user, however I'm not sure how to access the session values from within the urls.py.

What I have looks something like this:

```
 (r'^myrecords/$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Record.objects.filter(CURRENT LOGGED IN USER),
        context_object_name='record_list',
        template_name='records.html')),
```

What do I need to do?

Also is there any way to apply the login_required decorator to this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the docs on [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering).

You should subclass `ListView` and override the `get_queryset` method. When the class-based view is called, `self` is populated with the current request (`self.request`) as well as anything captured from the URL (`self.args`, `self.kwargs`).

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from myapp.models import Record

class MyRecordsListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'record_list'
    template_name = 'records.html',

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Record.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

There's also documentation for [decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views). Basically you can just decorate the result of `as_view` in your `urls.py`:

```
(r'^myrecords/$', login_required(MyRecordsListView.as_view())),
```