# Using ClassBasedViews I want to retrieve records from my database in Django based on the user's email, which is stored in a session

Tags: python, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-sessions, class-method

For the past 2hrs i've been trying to accomplish the following in Django 1.5: 
I want to retrieve records from my database based on the user's email, which is stored in a session. Here are my ideal algorithms:

```
In my function based view:
1. Attempt Login
2. If account exists, log user in and save email in request.session['email']

In my DetailView:
1.Get the email from the session and save it to a variable; email.
2. Create a queryset to retrieve the account filtering by email
```

I've referenced the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) and a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899113/get-request-session-from-a-class-based-generic-view) on this matter but can't seem to get my head around it. I decided to use the [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview) method to retrieve the session and it works...the only issue is i'm not sure how i can access the variable returned by this method. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/in-python-how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-class-methods) but didn't find it too helpful. If this question exist else where point me to it so i can delete this one. Thanks!

```
#views.py CBV snippet
class AccountDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Account
    template_name = 'accounts/view_account.html'
    queryset = Account.objects.filter(verified=1)
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.session['email']
        #just to make sure we've accessed the session...print to screen
        return HttpResponse(email)

#views.py FBV snippet
def AccountLogin(request):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form is not None:
            clean = form.cleaned_data
            try:
                #only allow login for verified accounts
                account = Account.objects.get(email=clean['email'])
                if account and account is not None and account.verified == 1:
                    #if account exist log user in
                    user = authenticate(username=clean['email'], password=clean['password'])
                    #we'll user this later to pull their account info
                    request.session['email'] = account.email
                    #logs user in
                    login(request, user)
```

This is the solution in a function based view...how do i implement it in class based view is what i'm asking.

```
def AccountView(request): 
    account = Account.objects.get(verified=1, email=request.session['email'])
    return render(request, 'accounts/view_account.html', {'account': account})
```

Comment: I'll leave this up here in case someone else has a similar question...I'm done with CBVs i'll just stick to FBVs.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it seriously wrong, and the problem is that I can't tell what is it that you're trying to accomplish. Class-based views are extremely simple and straightforward, and it's almost never necessary to override `get`˙and `post` methods.

Why are you storing the email in the session as it can be easily retrieved from the authenticated user?

Even in your FBV you're doing to many things unnecessarily; login is best left to a separate view, redirecting the user to the right view after authentication.

Comment: The issue i was having with the view was that it was retrieving all accounts instead of just the account of the logged in user. To fix the issue i decided to use a filter(Accounts.objects.filter(email=user's_email)) but to use the filter i needed the email variable and i wasn't sure how i could access the email variable without putting it in the url so, i decided to store it in a session and use the value in the session to run my query. In regard to getting the email from the authenticated user, how do i do that? I know login()
saves the user’s ID in the session, how do i access it in my view?

Comment: In a class-based view, the logged-in user is accessible as `self.request.user`.

Comment: Also, the `DetailView` expects either a `pk` or a `slug` parameter in its URLConf; in this case you're probably better off simply using a `TemplateView`, as there is no need for any extra filtering.

Comment: I tried the `self.request.user` in a get_queryset method and in the class just by itself(e.g. Accounts.object.filter(email=self.request.user)) but it didn't work. I'm aware of the pk/slug expectations but i don't want to pass these values via url. I originally did that until i discovered a security flaw...the flaw was the ability to access accounts of other users simply by passing a pk/slug in the url...of course i could've done some validations on the pk/slug to ensure it matched the currently logged in user but then what would be the point of using a generic view?!btw thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to use `DetailView` at all, simply use a `TemplateView` and access `request.user` in the template. You're overthinking it, try to simplify.

Comment: Thanks for all your help but it didn't work out for me. I'll stick with FBV for my current project and perhaps revisit CBV doc later for a better understanding of how they're used and when.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for in this thread [Django - Access session in urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718939/django-access-session-in-urls-py) I was definitely 'over-thinking' it and I also had no idea how to access the `self.request.user`. Even when I typed this solution in PyCharm editor I received a warning about `request` being inaccessible, probably because it's a dynamic value...below is my final solution.

```
#views.py
class AccountRead(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'account'
    template_name = 'accounts/view_account.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Account.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id)
```